# Nginx Access.log status results according to different file

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, status

nginx access.log,

I want to do

status="200" 
access_log  /var/log/access.log main;

status="444"
access_log  /var/log/access444.log main;

status="401"
access_log  /var/log/access401.log main;

this can be done?

Thnx

server {
    listen       5026;
    server_name  wwwww;

```
    if ($allowed_country = no) {
```

return 444;
}

```
if ($http_user_agent ~* "mozilla" ) {return 403; }



error_page   403 500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
}

location = / {
auth_basic            "Restricted";
auth_basic_user_file  /etc/nginx/users/user;
limit_conn peruser 2;
proxy_pass         http://localhost:9025;
proxy_redirect     off;

proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

access_log  /var/log/access.log main;

    }
```

}